# how to distribute different users to different `User` instances on locust workers?

Tags: python, performance-testing, locust

I'm using Locust for performance testing, and I want to use the distributed load feature. However, there is some bound condition that each user persists for only one session so each user instance should have a different logged-in user.

In my single process version of the locust file, I use a global set to `pop` a random user for each `User` instance:

```
idle_users = {id for id in range(1, 65535)}

class MyUser(FastHttpUser):
    __user: int = None

    def get_one_user(self):
        global idle_users
        self.__user = idle_users.pop()

    def on_stop(self):
        global idle_users
        idle_users.add(self.__user)
```

My question is, When coming into a distributed version of `get_one_user`, how can I access the global `idle_users` set, which is on the master instance on one machine, from a `MyUser` spawning on a worker instance that is on another machine?

note that I've read [the docs about the distributed-loading](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-distributed.html), but `@events.test_start` seems too early to init if I want the users on a node dynamically changes.

#### updated: 2022-05-24

About how the users work: `MyUser`s login by calling `on_start` and logout by `on_stop`. When logging in, a user is randomly fetched from the global set. When logout, the user is released to the global set so that it could be distributed again. That is, the users in `MyUser` instances and in remaining `idle_users` should dynamically change when swarming.

Comment: Does the number of users only change because of the `.pop()` or for an other reason too? Because you could avoid using `.pop()` and instead use `idle_users` as an iterator, e.g. with `idle_users = iter(range(12345))` and `self.__users = next(idle_users)`

Comment: I can change it if I increase or decrease when swarming